# Perl exec command failing

Tags: perl

I'm trying to execute a shell command via a perl script that looks as follows

```
 $cmd = 'cat <(ssh -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" dev-adm1 \'sudo cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf\')';
 exec $cmd;
```

This is throwing an error

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(ssh -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" dev-adm1 'sudo cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf')'
```

The command works directly on the shell but not like this. What am i missing?

Comment: you are `exec()` cat, not shell. cat doesn't understand `()`. Use `system()` otherwise build & run the command from you shell as `YOUR_SHELL cat XXXX`, then replace in perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which shell did you use to test this command?

my first guess is that you used bash or ksh, while sh (used by perl exec) doesn't know the '(' syntax